# Rounding up the values in a crystal reports cross tab

Tags: crystal-reports, field, rounding, crosstab, crystal-reports-xi

I'm creating a report in a cross tab with Crystal Reports XI.
The rows are dates, the columns are business areas and the fields are the average response time, which should be rounded up to the the next whole number (that is 17,1 is to be rounded to 18).
Response time is a formula, and I use cross tab to calculate and show the average.

Rounding in field settings only allows to set the number of decimal places to round to, but does not allow for more fine tuning as fas as I can see.

I have found the `RoundUp()` function, but I can't find how to incorporate that in the field settings of a crosstab.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the display string of the crosstab field to: `cStr(RoundUp(Val(currentfieldvalue)))`

Comment: Thanks! Also found `ToText(RoundUp(CurrentFieldValue),0)`